# Get balance json from Nexmo API with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, vonage

Cheers! I'm using nexmo gem in my Rails project, so, I want to get json with my balance with `get_balance` method, but I get:

`#<Nexmo::Response:0x007ff0c7214138 @http_response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @json=JSON>`

but when I trying the same thing with curl

`curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance/\{#######\}/\{#######\}`

It gives me exactly what I want:

```
{"value":0.02}
```

So, how to handle Nexmo::Response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have to call either response.body or response.object from the result of the "get_balance" execution.

ex:

```
r = call_get_balance
```

You need the r.body or r.object, where the body will be as is and object the body as json.